# Using comma as a decimal mark with SageTeX

Tags: punctuation, sagetex

There are a lot of questions about how-to use comma instead of dot in standart LaTeX documents. But how i can do this in documents with SageTeX?
P.S. I use online editor cloud.sagemath.com

Comment: If Sagetex used [tag:siunitx] to represent quantities, then this could be configured with an \sisetup command in the preamble.  Unfortunately, I think it does not.

Comment: @CharlesStewart Outspokenly, if comments could be downvoted, your would get it. SageTeX outputs only numbers, and not quantities or anything such. Using `siunitx` would be unnecessary added step into this already very complicated process.

Comment: @user46170 I don't think that solution on the LaTeX's side is something reasonable. This needs to be solved inside Sage. Question about it are best asked at [ask.sagemath.com](http://ask.sagemath.com), which is a Q&A site like this one, just it's unrelated to StackExchange.

Comment: @tohecz - siunitx does handle dimensionless quantities (use \num).  Discussion of whether this sort of qn is on topic should go to meta.

Comment: @CharlesStewart The question _is_ on-topic. I just say it would get a better answer there than here. And I know `siunitx` is able to handle it, but it is an overkill. As I explained, SageTeX is already quite complicated. No need to go further in this direction.

Comment: @tohecz Where is the high cost associated with siunitx?  It is one of the most core, most trusted packages for Latex.  Are you worried about compile time?  The extra six characters that need to be typed for each multi-digit number?  The complexity of telling Sage to put something in preamble?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13043/discussion-between-tohecz-and-charles-stewart)

Comment: Just for clarification, is this the sort of thing you're asking to do?  "Consider $\pi\sim \sage{str(N(pi)).replace('.',',')}$"    It outputs in the wrong font though.

Comment: I suppose this feature request for Sage is relevant: http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/8594